Azure Release Pipeline - Execute a PowerShell script from a remote server
I need to create a release pipeline for coping two .dll files and remotely execute a PowerShell script.
What I did,

Wrote a bash script to download the .dll file and PowerShell script file from GitHub.


I have an onPrem agent server (onPrem1/172.24.243.193) and the files have downloaded to that
server (D:\agent_work\r65\a\DeploymentPackage\ReleaseFiles) - SUCCESSFUL


Used Windows Machine File Copy (WinRM) to copy the .dll file to a remote server (AppServer1/172.26.143.22). The location: D:\release\ - SUCCESSFUL
Used the PowerShell v2.* to execute the downloaded PowerShell script - FAILED

onPrem agent is in different network (172.24.243.193) and remote server is in another network (172.26.143.22).
The PowerShell script includes;

Check whether there is an existing .dll file in the remote location.
If there is an existing file, copy that file to backup folder.
Copy the new .dll file from D:\release\ to D:\app\
Restart the AKServ windows service.

As I am running the PowerShell script from onPrem agent server, and the .dll file is in different network how can I resolve this issue.
function Backup-file {
param(
[String] $serverName, 
[String] $fileName
)

$releaseFolderPath = "\\$serverName\d$\app\"
$backupFileDirectory = "$releaseFolderPath\Backups\"

Write-Host "Backing up $releaseFolderPath to $backupFileDirectory"

$releaseFileFullPath = Join-Path -Path $releaseFolderPath -ChildPath $fileName


if (Test-Path -Path $releaseFileFullPath){
Write-Host "File Exists $releaseFileFullPath "
    try {
        # Create the Backup folder if it doesn't exist
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $backupFileDirectory)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupFileDirectory
            Write-Host "Backup folder created on $backupFileDirectory"
        }

        #Rename & Move the exsisting release file
        $backupFileName = "ABC_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".dll"
        $backupFileFullPath = Join-Path -Path $backupFileDirectory -ChildPath $backupFileName

        $tempFile = Join-Path -Path $releaseFolderPath -ChildPath $backupFileName 
        Write-Host "Temp file $tempFile"

        Rename-Item -Path $backupFileFullPath -NewName $backupFileName
        Move-Item -Path $tempFile -Destination $backupFileDirectory

        Write-Host "File backup and rename successful in Server !!!"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
}else{
    Write-Host "Error: File not found $releaseFileFullPath!!!"
}


}

function Copy-Source-Files {
    try{
    Write-Host "Copy-Source-Files started .."
    $releaseFilePath = Join-Path $sourceFolderPath -ChildPath $fileName

    Write-Host "Release path: $releaseFilePath appServerReleaseFolderPath: $appServerReleaseFolderPath"
    Copy-Item -Path $releaseFilePath -Destination $appServerReleaseFolderPath
    }
    catch{
    Write-Host "Error occured in Copy-Source-Files $_"
    }
}


function Restart-Service {
param(
[String] $ServerName, 
[String] $ServiceName

)
Write-Host "Restarting $ServiceName of $ServerName"

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $plaintextPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $securePassword)

    $scriptBlock = {
        param($Service)
        Restart-Service -Name $Service -Force
    }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $ServiceName -Credential $credential
}


function Restart-Service {

$appService = "AKServ"

Restart-Service -ServerName $ServerName -ServiceName $appService

}


try{

$isValid = Validate-Source-File

if(!$isValid){
    Write-Host "File is not valid $fileName"
    return 
}

Write-Host "Processing Started...."

Backup-file -serverName $appServerName -fileName $fileName

#Copy-Source-Files
Restart-Services

Write-Host "Release completed ..."

}catch{
Write-Host "Error occured .. $_"

}




As I am running the PowerShell script from onPrem agent server, and the .dll file is in different network how can I resolve this issue.

You can copy the PowerShell script file along with the .dll file to the remote server, and then use the PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 task to run the PowerShell script directly on the remote server.
Here’s how you can set it up:

Use a bash script task to download the .dll file and PowerShell script file from GitHub to the onPrem agent server (onPrem1/172.24.243.193).
Use Windows Machine File Copy (WinRM) task to copy the .dll file and PowerShell script file to the remote server (AppServer1/172.26.143.22).
Use the "PowerShell on Target Machines" task to run the PowerShell script on the target machine.  Then enter the target machine's IP address or hostname, provide the necessary credentials, and specify the path to the PowerShell script.

Please check the Prerequisites of the task and make sure that Windows Remote Management (WinRM) is properly configured on the target machines and that the necessary network configurations are in place to allow communication between the machines.
